# Checking if an array is sorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to build a program that accepts an array of integers as parameter and returns a String. The string would be "ascending" if the array is sorted from the smallest to the greatest, "descending" if the array is sorted from the greatest to the smallest, "not sorted" is the array is not sorted at all and "all the same" if all elements of the array are equal.

So far I have the following code below. Am I on the right track? I keep getting an error on the line indicated below saying "The operator > is undefined for the argument type". Any idea what could cause it?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        arrayInput();
        isSorted(null);
    }

    public static String arrayInput() {
        int size = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");
        size = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The size you enetered is " + size);
        int[] array = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter the array: ");
        int j = 0;
        while (j < size) {
            System.out.print("Enter int"+ (j + 1) + ": ");
            array[j] = in.nextInt();
            ++j;
        }
        in.close();
        String arrayS = Arrays.toString(array);
        return arrayS;
    }

    public static String isSorted(String[] arrayS) {
        int n = arrayS.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
            if (arrayS[i] > arrayS[i + 1])   //ERROR ON THIS LINE
                return "not ascending";
        return "ascending";
    }
}
```

Comment: " I am still a newbie to java so bare with me!" - I'm not getting bare with anybody, whether they know Java or not.  I might be willing to bear with your question, though.

Comment: lol my bad with the typo mate!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error means that the operator `>` is not defined for the `String` type, which is the element type of your arrays. The operators `<` and `>` are only usable on primitive types like `int` or `long`, not on objects.

Here you need to use [`String.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) instead, like this:

```
    if (arrayS[i].compareTo(arrayS[i+1]) > 0)
```

Comment: I had no idea! But I understand now. Thanks for the informative answer Peter. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`String` implements [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29), which allows you to compare the value of two objects (the form for the interface is actually `Comparator<E>`, so you're using `Comparator<String>`).

So, instead of:

```
for (int i=0;i<n-1;++i) {
    if (arrayS[i]>arrayS[i+1]) {
        // Stuff
```

...you should use:

```
for (int i=0;i<n-1;++i) {
    if (arrayS[i].compareTo(arrayS[i+1]) > 0) {
        // Stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

The user enters an array of integers, so the type of the array should be kept as int[]. For example:

```
public static int[] arrayInput() {
    // ...
    return array;
}

public static String isSorted(int[] arrayS) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: therefore the second method is where i should convert the int array to a string array?

Comment: @theolc, no, the input is arriving as text, and if you want to store it in an `int[]` array, you need to convert each `String` into an `int` first, using e.g. [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). Then you can process the `int[]` instead of `String[]`, and actually compare the `int`s in your array with `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making things more complicated than they need to be.

1. In arrayInput you create an int[] and then convert it to a String.  Why?
2. In isSorted you take a String[] and check if it is sorted.

   1. If you insist #1 should produce a String, why does #2 take a String[] as input.
   2. I think your isSorted code would work pretty well as is, if the input were an int[]
3. There is nothing connecting arrayInput with isSorted.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative strategy. Calculate what the ascending and descending arrays would be, then just see if it matches. This might be less efficient but it's pretty fool-proof and easy to implement/debug. I only had to box the primitive array in order to do a reverse sort.

```
private static void isSorted(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> boxed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i : array) {
        boxed.add(i);
    }
    List<Integer> ascending = new ArrayList<Integer>(boxed);
    Collections.sort(ascending);

    List<Integer> descending = new ArrayList<Integer>(ascending);
    Collections.reverse(descending);

    if (boxed.equals(ascending)) {
        System.out.println("Ascending");
    } else if (boxed.equals(descending)) {
        System.out.println("Descending");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unsorted");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do the sort twice - you can just use `Collections.reverse()`. You can probably also use `Arrays.asList()` to create the list in the first place.